# Wrong output in program - returning words in two strings (python)

Tags: python

```
def words_in_both(string1, string2):
    s = set()
    res = []
    for word in string1.lower().split():
        if word not in s: s.add(word)
    for word in string2.lower().split():
        if word in s: res.append(word)
    return res

print(words_in_both("Here is my MY test1","Here IS My MY mY test2"))
```

I'm running into errors in my code, I'm trying to only return the words in both strings regardless of capitalization, but when I run my code I'm returning: ['here', 'is', 'my', 'my', 'my']

Can someone help me identify my issue?

Comment: Your code is doing that. What are you expecting as output?

Comment: I was expecting: here is my

Comment: Just change if word in s: res.append(word) to if word in s and not word in res: res.append(word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tool is indeed returning words in both strings, however you have not accounted that those words might be present multiple times. If you want a unique list, you should cast to a set, and then back to a list.

See below code for reference:

```
def words_in_both(string1, string2):
    s = set()
    res = []
    for word in string1.lower().split():
        if word not in s: s.add(word)
    for word in string2.lower().split():
        if word in s: res.append(word)
    return list(set(res)) #Changed line

print(words_in_both("Here is my MY test1","Here IS My MY mY test2"))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me realize this, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the result to set then back to list to avoid duplicates

```
def words_in_both(string1, string2):
    s = set()
    res = []
    for word in string1.lower().split():
        if word not in s: s.add(word)
    for word in string2.lower().split():
        if word in s: res.append(word)
    return list(set(res))

print(words_in_both("Here is my MY test1","Here IS My MY mY test2"))
```

Output: `['here', 'is', 'my']`

Comment: Ah of course, thanks a lot for helping me realize this!